# Django creates only one related name of ForeignKey instead of two

Tags: django

There is a model:

```
class Transfer(models.Model):
    when = models.DateTimeField()
    _from = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="income_transfers")
    to = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="outcome_transfers"),
    total = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

There is a use case:

```
income_transfers_total = sum((x.total for x in _user.income_transfers.all()))
outcome_transfers_total = sum((x.total for x in _user.outcome_transfers.all()))  # error line
```

Last string returns

```
'User' object has no attribute 'outcome_transfers'
```

Debugger shows that user object really has only "income_transfers" but not "oucome transfer". Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the comma between to and total in your model and make and run migrations again.